# New field on shipping address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm building a store with Rails and Spree Commerce. The products are basically personalised kits that will be send as a gift to another person.

So, when you do the ckeckout you need to use the form "shipping address" and put your friend's address.

But, there is no "message" field.

The people how send these gift want to send with it a card with some text like "Happy birthday John!" or something like that.

I don't know how to handle this, is there any extension to do that? Or I have to modify the core code of Spree?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can give you the exact code but I think I can point you in the right direction. So a user browsers your site, adds a few items to the cart and proceeds to the checkout page where they enter their friends shipping address.

`rails generate Order name:string friends_name:string shipping_address:text email:string attatched_message:text`

**attatched_message** would be the personalized message. Then all you need to do is add the order to the model used to pass items from the shopping cart to the order form. ex.

`rails generate migration add_order_to_line_item order:references`